# My SO is going abroad and I'll most likely move to live with her in less than a year. Should my employer know?

Tags: professionalism, recommendation-letter, visa

I have been with my current employer for couple of months now. So far I am extremely satisfied with the job, the only "problem" is that my SO is going abroad for couple of years. At this point there is 90% chance that she'll stay there and that I'll move there as well to live with her. I do not want to outright lie to my coworkers/employer, but we are flying there in couple of months and I am flying back alone - on one hand I do not want to tell them the complete truth, on the other I can't lie them for a year that my SO is actually living with me when she's many miles away.

Also at some point I might need recommendations from them and given that we're from Europe, moving into Canada, I'll probably need these recommendations many months before starting the new job. It's a weird situation. They most likely won't give me very good recommendations if I were to lie to them about moving away. On the other hand saying the complete truth limits me in terms of development in my current position. I do not think that they would outright fire me. But their behaviour would definitely be different given my limited "workspan". Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to "lie [to] them for a year that my SO is actually living with me"? Do you have close friends there and that would come up in daily conversation? Do you have benefits or similar which are dependent on living with your SO? If it comes up, what's wrong with saying she's spending some time abroad without going into details?

Comment: And consider that when you are ready to move, your company might let you work remotely. Or you may no longer even be working for that company for other reasons.

Comment: ad Dukeling - Well small talk is small talk and can't be avoided. I was thinking about saying exactly what you're suggesting.
ad HLGEM: I was thinking about that, but living on my wage in Canada in real terms wouldn't be exactly the best solution either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to lie about her leaving. It's perfectly fine to let your coworkers/management know as "casual information". You can talk about it as smalltalk, it's part of your life and you can share it if you wish to do so. People might make hypotheses out of it, but as long as you're acting cool, there's no reason for it to raise concerns. Just keep doing what you were doing and everything should be fine. You can also say part of the truth and not delve too much into details (it's your personal life, after all) if you don't feel like being too accurate.

The thing is, leaving your job to follow one's SO is a relatively common thing. It happens pretty much everytime, everywhere, and if your company representatives are being professional, there won't be any hard feelings. Leaving is a possibility of every day, and you can't reasonably resent someone for simply leaving (unless there's a particular context), for any reason.

As for the recommendation letters, it's all boiling down to how long you will have been working there when you explain the situation. You obviously have to explain that you will probably be leaving in a few months when asking for them, and even if you've been very productive, it might be ill-perceived to request a recommendation letter if you've not been there long enough. This means you have to wait, even if you feel like you'll be lying for some time. I wouldn't go for it before having worked at least 6 months; I'm not experienced in the "recommendation letter" subject, but I've managed to get good references from an employer I've only worked with for 3 months, so I believe this is enough.

Wait until you've proved you worth, then inform management of your desire to leave in a few months. That should take care of the recommendation. They will be able to assess your performance and judge if you indeed deserve a good one, and they will probably appreciate the heads-up : bear in mind that when leaving, the only period you have to respect is your notice; I don't know how long it is where you work, but if you manage to tell them something like 6 months prior to your leaving, they will have time to think about how they will handle the situation. If you can give them an approximate date (like, a month) when you think you will be leaving, it's even better, but don't be too accurate, the only moment when you have to give a date is when you give your notice.

When you say that their behavior will definitely be different once you tell them, is it based on evidence/observation ? *(I'll let you answer this in the comments and will edit my answer accordingly.)* If you insist on the fact that you've had a positive experience and on your motivation to keep working at full pace until you effectively leave, they have no reason to treat you differently. You can tell them you're ready to take some time at the end to organize knowledge transfer sessions with the person/people who will be taking your workload. If they trust you and are satisfied with your work, they have no reason to take your workload from you. And if they do, well, it's a good thing you're leaving.

Answer (score 5):

You don't know the future, and things could change.  Therefore, you don't want to inform your company now of things that may or may not happen (even if they are fairly likely).

Continue with your work now as if you will be there a long time.  If the time comes that you need to give notice, give the appropriate amount of notice.  Because life changes, and they are aware of that too.

It's possible that by the time you do give notice that you will have been there for a reasonable amount of time.  They certainly will have a better idea of your work after more months there, and if you are a great worker now, you will increase your chances of getting a good recommendation.

Comment: Things could change. That's a great point - thanks for your answer!